# Ubuntu Studio 21.10 Freezing, Requires Hard Reset

Tags: freeze, gpu, 21.10, ubuntu-studio, amdgpu

I can't seem to figure out the exact cause of the freezing. It seems to happen most often during video playback (Hulu, Netflix) in fullscreen mode and during gameplay through steam, but it's also frozen during normal web browsing and just moving around in the file manager and terminal. The screen will freeze and the last second or two of audio will loop. The keyboard is unresponsive but I can sometimes move the mouse (clicks don't register). I've tried waiting to see if it unsticks itself but I end up having to hard reset.

I've tried memtest86 and it passed fine, I've also tried updating drivers and it didn't seem to make a difference. The cpu and gpu both are running well under their maximum heat/load when these crashes occur. I included the contents of /var/crash. Any suggestions on what might be causing the issue would be appreciated. I'm not sure what other information would be useful so please let me know.

Edit: I went through the possible fixes in the linked question. Adding swap space and adding "pci=nomsi" into grub didn't seem to affect the issue. Updating the BIOS to my manufacturer's most recent version seemed to fix the issue.

```
Operating System: Ubuntu Studio 21.10
KDE Plasma Version: 5.22.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.86.0
Qt Version: 5.15.2
Kernel Version: 5.13.0-23-lowlatency (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 16 × AMD Ryzen 7 3800XT 8-Core Processor
Memory: 31.1 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: AMD Radeon RX 550 / 550 Series
```

```
ls -al /var/crash
total 5520
drwxrwsrwt  2 root  whoopsie    4096 Jan  6 21:07 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root  root        4096 Oct 12 13:53 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root  whoopsie       0 Jan  6 21:06 kdump_lock
-rw-r--r--  1 root  whoopsie     327 Jan  6 21:07 kexec_cmd
-rw-r-----  1 sddm  whoopsie       0 Jan  6 20:24 _usr_bin_autojack.120.crash
-rw-r-----  1 ernst whoopsie 5640192 Jan  6 20:27 _usr_bin_kwin_x11.1000.crash
```